# unable to create '/var/www/html/myproject/.git/index.lock' read-only file system

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I followed many answers related on my problem but did not work for me.

when i run on server

`git pull`

i got this error

`unable to create '/var/www/html/myproject/.git/index.lock' read-only file system`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your filesystem has just damaged for some reason, and the OS remounted with read-only. You may try to reboot your system.